# Inserting a python dictionary key/values into javascript lists with Jinja/Flask

Tags: python, jinja2

I'm using ChartJs to display some data, my chart is defined like so:

```
var myChart = new Chart(ctx1, {
       type: 'pie',
       data: {
           labels: ['label1', 'label2', 'label3', 'label4'],
           datasets: [{
               label: 'Chart 1',
               data: [12, 19, 100, 5],
               backgroundColor: [
                   'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                   'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                   'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                   'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
               ],
               borderColor: [
                   'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                   'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                   'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                   'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
               ],
               borderWidth: 1
           }]
       },
       options: {
       }
   });
```

The variable `label` I would like to populate with keys from a python dictionary

```
chart_data = {'A':10, 'B':5, 'C':7, 'D':15}
```

and the `data` variable populated with the dictionary values, so what I'd end up with in my javascript is

```
           labels: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
           datasets: [{
               label: 'Chart 1',
               data: [10, 5, 7, 15],
```

I'm just not sure how to iterate a dictionary with Jinja to only return the keys, and to only return the values, into a JavaScript list.

Can I use a Jinja for/loop to iterate inside a javascript list? It doesnt seem to work

```
some_js_var = [{% for x in y %} {{ x }} {% endfor %}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assigned my python dictionary to a JS variable like so:

```
var data_from_python = {{ python_dict|tojson }}
```

Then to just assign the keys to a variable as a list:

```
labels: Object.keys(data_from_python),
```

and same the values in the data

```
data: Object.values(data_from_python)
```

What I end up with is

```
labels: ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
data: [10, 5, 7, 15]
```